# undefined method `layout' for #<HelloController:0x101d7edb0> from Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to switch the layout using Ruby on Rails but I am getting the error: undefined method `layout' for #. I am using Rails 2.3.5 Am I missing an include?

Here is the code:

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController

  def index

    layout 'standard'
    @message = "Goodbye!"
    @count = 3
    @bonus = "This is the bonus message!"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using `layout` as such, it goes in the Class definition, not an action.

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController

  layout 'standard'

  def index
    ...
```

This is saying that you want to use this layout for rendering all actions in this controller.

If you want a specific layout for that one action, you would use `render :layout` as so:

```
  def index
    @message =
    ...
    render :layout => 'standard'
  end
```

EDIT: [the docs](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods.html#M001596) (towards the bottom) seem to suggest that you need to specify the action, as well as the layout when using a specific layout for one action. I don't remember that being the case, but if it is, the above would be `render :action => 'index', :layout => 'standard'`.